# Integration of the form (ax+b)^n

Tags: calculus

My textbook uses the follwoing rule to integrate functions of the form $(ax+b)^n$. [Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1blNX.png)

However it notes that the rule only works for powers of linear functions, which seems unintuitive to me.

Finding the derivative of the function $(4x^2+3)^5$ can be found using the chain rule. However when applying this rule to $(4x^2+3)^5$ can not be done, as the expression in the brackets must be linear. What's the reasoning for this? Seems unintuitive.

I am looking for a proof or intuition for why the function must be linear.

Comment: Can you explain what the reverse chain rule is? I am unfamiliar with it.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we are trying to find $$\int (4x^2+3)^5 dx.$$ The chain rule specifies that
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(u(x)) = f'(u(x))\cdot u'(x).$$

The reverse chain rule (I've never heard of this terminology but google exists, most people call it a $u$-sub) is basically pattern matching. Our goal is to set some inner function (the $u(x)$ in the example) and find the derivative, and hope that we can find a $u'(x)$ on the end and an $f'(u(x)).$

Let's see what happens when we apply it to a linear case: suppose we want to find
$$\int (3x+1)^7 dx.$$
We set $$u(x) = 3x+1 \implies u'(x) = 3 \iff u'(x)/3 = 1$$
so just by plugging in we have
$$\int (3x+1)^7 dx = \int u(x)^7 u'(x)/3 dx = \frac{u(x)^8}{8 \cdot 3} + C = (3x+1)^8/24 + C.$$

The important thing to recognize here is that $u'(x)$ was constant, which only happens when the inner term is linear. Let's go back to your problem: $$u(x) = 4x^2 + 3 \implies u'(x) = 8x \iff u'(x)/8x = 1.$$
When we try to write $(4x^2+3)^5$ in terms of $f'(u(x)) \cdot u'(x)$, it doesn't work out well:
$$(4x^2+3)^5 = u(x)^5 = u(x)^5 \cdot u'(x)/8x.$$
This does not have an easily integrable form because it is not in the form that we'd like for the chain rule. (Integrating by parts won't be much better either.)  It is surely integrable (I would personally just expand the polynomial and integrate each of the terms,) but u-subbing (reverse chain rule) does not intuitively work here.

You'll find that $\int (4x^2 + 3)^5 \cdot x dx$ is much easier to find and I invite you to try it to see what I mean.